# Where do you find the source code of keyboard shortcut application?

Tags: shortcut-keys, source-code

Where do you find the source code of application that allows you to customize the keyboard shortcut that is built into ubuntu? The application that I am talking about is shown in the image below.

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Please refer to this [help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exclusive package. The keyboard shortcuts-layout..etc is part of package `gnome-settings-daemon`.

See it for your self. Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue the following

```
apt-cache show gnome-settings-daemon
```

and read the description.

```
Description-en: daemon handling the GNOME session settings
 This package contains the daemon which is responsible for setting the
 various parameters of a GNOME session and the applications that run
 under it. It handles the following kinds of settings:
 .
  * Keyboard: layout, accessibility options, shortcuts, media keys
  * Clipboard management
  * Theming: background, icons, GTK+ applications
  * Cleanup of unused files
  * Mouse: cursors, speed, accessibility options
  * Startup of other daemons: screensaver, sound daemon
  * Typing break
 .
 It also sets various application settings through X resources and
 freedesktop.org XSETTINGS.
```

So if you want to do something with the settings, I guess you should download the source code of `gnome-settings-daemon` package.